# how to remove fingerprint or face icon from popup in local authentication in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny9aI.jpg)I am trying to develop face and fingerprint authentication in a flutter app. I need to do both are in separately in my app. But if the user registered both fingerprint and face id in his mobile when I try to develop a fingerprint module it shows both face and fingerprint icons in the popup. can anyone tell me how to remove either face or finger in the popup?

Comment: Hi! Could you provide your code and screenshot of authentication popup?

Comment: Mol0ko - please check the screen in my question...

Comment: Add the code you are using along with the library

Comment: @LoganathanK local_auth package does not support biometrics type selection, you only can check available biometric types via `getAvailableBiometrics()` method